# Flatlist freezes when `onEndReached` is triggered

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react native and I have a flatlist that can render anywhere from 2 items to over 2000. Due to this, it's really important to optimize the performance to make sure the Flatlist doesn't lag. I've tried to optimize performance with the props provided in the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration). However, I noticed when I scroll down to the bottom and my `loadMoreData` function is called, scrolling freezes for like 1 second. How can I make it so this doesn't happen? Thank you.

Code:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState(mockData);

  // Load more data
  const loadMoreData = () => {
    setData((prevItems) => {
      return [...new Set([...prevItems, ...testItem])]; // 'testItem' is an array with one object that 
    });
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
        extraData={data}
        data={data}
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
          length: 78, 
          offset: 78 * index, 
          index,
        })}
        initialNumToRender={7}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
        windowSize={10}
        onEndReached={loadMoreData} // freezes when this is called
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <>
            <Swipeable renderRightActions={(progress, dragX) =>}>
              <HoldItem items={InventoryHoldMenuItems}>
                <Layout>
                  <InventoryItem item={item} />
                </Layout>
              </HoldItem>
            </Swipeable>
          </>
        )}
      />
    )}
  )
```

Comment: I think the way you concatenated the two lists is suspicious. My guess is, that react-native doesn't realize, that the beginning of your data didn't change and therefore has to rerender the whole FlatList.
Can you try `return prevItems.concat(testItem)` instead?

Comment: It still is lagging.

Comment: Can you debug, when what is called? Is `loadMoreData` only called, when you expect it to? If so, is `renderItem` only called once after the load?

Comment: I just tested this on my iphone and it loads no problem with no lag. I think it was lagging on my computer because I'm running it in android emulator with a bunch of other things open. Would this be the problem?

Comment: Maybe, but it's still weird, that your emulator needs 1 second to render a single new item. That's why I would debug if that is actually the case.